# If [Ticket] value is the same, but Cabin value is missing for one the items, fill in with value (Titanic)

Tags: pandas, numpy

```
      Fare Cabin  Pclass  Ticket  
257  86.50     B       1  110152   
504  86.50     B       1  110152   
759  86.50     B       1  110152   
585  79.65     E       1  110413   
262  79.65     E       1  110413  
219  10.500   NaN      2  W/C14208   
745  71.000     B      1  WE/P5735   
540  71.000     B      1  WE/P5735 
244  23.450   NaN      3  W./C.6607   
888  23.450   NaN      3  W./C.6607   
783  23.450   NaN      3  W./C.6607   
33   23.450   NaN      3  W./C.6607 
475  52.0       A      1  110465    
110  52.0       C      1  110465   
305  151.55     C      1  113781   
297  151.55     C      1  113781   
306  151.55     C      1  113781   
498  151.55     C      1  113781   
708  151.55   NaN      1  113781   
141  151.55   NaN      1  113781
```

Above is a sample of the  dataset. 
First I'm grouping all Tickets who have the same numerical value together, then I'm checking if that group has more than one unique Cabin value.
For example, Ticket #110152 has only one unique Cabin value, 'B'.
One the other hand Ticket #113781 has a couple of unique values, 'C' and 'NaN'.
For those group of tickets with more than one unique Cabin value, but one least one of those Cabin values has to be a 'Nan'  value (so ticket #110465 which has two unique Cabin Values will NOT fit the criteria), I want those 'Nan' values to be filled by the non-null value in the group.

So,   Ticket # 113781 Cabin values would all be 'C'

```
305  151.55     C      1  113781   
297  151.55     C      1  113781   
306  151.55     C      1  113781   
498  151.55     C      1  113781   
708  151.55     C     1  113781   
141  151.55     C     1  113781
```

Below is a code that I worked on:

```
for i, j in df.groupby('Ticket'):
    if j.Ticket.count() >1 :   # This checks if there is more than one ticket in the group
    if len(j.Cabin.unique())>1:   #This checks if there is more than one unique value
        for i in j.Cabin.values[(j.Cabin.values== np.nan.all(1))]: #I was attempting to find out those groups with at least one 'Nan'  value. But this code wasn't working. I tried different iterations but I couldn't get this working.
```

I played around with j.Cabin.values for a while but I don't really know how to smartly set up boolean values and extract 'Nan' values.

Comment: What should happen if a group has a null `Cabin` value but also more than one non-null values?

Comment: Good question.  In that case, either one of those non-null values are okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***option 1***
`bfill` and `ffill`

```
def bffill(s):
    return s.bfill().ffill()

df['Cabin'] = df.groupby('Ticket').Cabin.apply(bffill)
```

***option 2***
`transform` + `first` + `combine_first`

```
df['Cabin'] = df.Cabin.combine_first(df.groupby('Ticket').Cabin.transform('first'))
```

***note*** that for index `110` you have a different cabin on the same ticket.  The combine first ensures that I don't overwrite the original cabin value.

---

Both yield

[image]

Comment: Yeah, you had taught me about `bfill` before, but due to index `110` I felt like I couldn't use it in this case. I purposely made sure to include the `110` case here as there are several similar cases throughout the dataframe. I will take a closer look at your solutions and see if I understand them thoroughly. Thanks!

Comment: @moondra If you want them to be consistent within ticket groups, you'll have to choose which to take.  The `transform` solution can be used without the `combine_first` component to overwrite all values in the group with the first value found.  Also, you could use `transform('last')` to use the last valid value found.

Comment: Ah. It seems I was mistaken about ` bfill`. I assumed it would fill the value irrespective of  null or non-null. However, upon testing and reading the docs more carefully, it seems It only fills NA values, which should work in this case ( I think).  I'm going to play around with combine_first and transform for a bit as well.

Comment: Oops. I just saw your comment.

Comment: First valid value in group

Comment: So transform('first/last') always excludes 'nan' values?
Thank you so much for your help.